# Selecting an Arduino for automotive Dashboard

Tags: arduino, automotive

In an upcoming project I need to design a custom dashboard for a race car (in a student design competition). There would be at least 3-4 sensors that would need interfacing and a graphic LCD to display the stats.

My preferred choice for the processor board is an Arduino because of the number of libraries available, the cost factor and the relative ease and rapidity of development.

Where I am stuck, however, is choosing the exact processor. With 32 kB of flash and 2 kB RAM, the Uno seems a decent enough and a cheaper choice while the Arduino Mega 2560 would be more than sufficient for my needs. 
My initial choice was the Arduino Uno (processor: ATMega328) but considering the fairly intensive nature of the application I am giving it another thought.

1) Is there any other alternative besides the Arduino that I might have overlooked?

2) Which is a better choice for this particular application? (Note: cost is a -key variable here)

3) On an slightly unrelated topic, how do you usually estimate the RAM usage of a particular application for choosing a processor (considering you have sufficient flash)?

I'll be programming mostly in C with some Processing-like code.

Comment: How is cost a key variable? Does your grade depend on it, or are you just trying to keep the cost of your single prototype down? In what way is your application “intensive” ?

Comment: If cost is a real concern, it is cheaper to build your own microcontroller circuit from scratch than to use a development board such as Arduino. You can still use the Arduino libraries, although there is really no need to do so. Based on the information you have given, RAM should not be a concern unless your graphics LCD is very intensive. Do you need a "graphics display" or just an alphanumeric one? Without knowing more about the LCD you intend to use, I can't really recommend a specific MCU or board. Although I'd bet the mega328 would work fine.

Comment: There are many ARM microcontrollers you might consider as well, especially if you need more than the limited RAM available on the ATMEGA devices, or more computational power.  In terms of estimation, one technique is to implement your algorithms in portable C code (targeting a PC), at least to the point of getting a conceptual idea of the size of your data structures.

Answer (score 3):

For the kind of application described in the question, concerns for consideration include **power spikes**, **EMI** / transients on sensor inputs, and tough **environmental conditions**.

Assuming that the LCD selected has a capable controller on board, and supports display primitives instead of just bit-blasting, the microcontroller memory is not a critical area. Such a controller is recommended anyway, so that display updates can be reasonably fast without unduly consuming microcontroller clock cycles.

On the other hand, "dumb" LCD controllers which require all updates to be full-screen pixel maps, will strain the memory available in even an Arduino Mega 2560. Directly driving an LCD panel without a controller may not even merit consideration.

Keeping the above views in mind, an **Arduino Uno will most likely suffice** from a processor / RAM perspective, with some optimized coding effort, of course.

---

To address the environmental and power / input line transient concerns, one recommendation is the [Ruggeduino](http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/ruggeduino.html), a **ruggedized Arduino Uno** compatible board with fully buffered IOs, very good power protection and overall robustness far outshining any official Arduino board:

[image: Ruggeduino]

The 30 mA reset-able fuses and 24 Volt tolerance on every IO pin will probably justify the choice instantly. The board is fully compatible with the Arduino Uno, and cost-wise, the $39.95 is not significantly higher than the cost of the Arduino Uno.

---

The question does not clarify which specific sensors are needed; One option could be the [Gadget Shield](http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/gadget_shield.html), by the same manufacturers:

[image: Gadget Shield]

From the product pages, this shield provides:

> accelerometer, speaker, microphone, infrared transmitter, infrared receiver, RGB LED, four discrete LED’s, two pushbuttons, a potentiometer, and a visible light sensor

---

The **weak link in this project will be the LCD panel** itself. Under the extreme conditions a race car faces, the LCD panel will face risk of the glass breaking, or contacts coming off, at the least.

While ruggedized displays are available, their pricing is orders of magnitude higher than hobby LCD panels, even ones with high-end controllers. So long as the purpose of the project is not mission-critical, i.e. nobody would be at risk if the LCD failed in live deployment, that additional cost may be unjustified for a student project.